# Babel doesn't ignore node_modules directory, although it is in "ignore" config

Tags: node.js, compression, minify, babeljs

For some reason `babel` doesn't ignore `node_modules` directory, although I specified it in `"ignore"` field of `.babelrc` file. Why does it happen? How to make `babel` act as expected?

My goal is to compress and mangle all `.js` files in my ExpressJS app (particularly my all back end code) before I push my app to remote repo and then to server. So I use `babel` and `babili`.

Here is my `.babelrc` config:

```
{
    "presets": [
        ["latest", {
            "modules": false
        }]
    ],
    "env": {
        "development": {
            "presets": ["stage-0", "react", "babili"]
        },
        "production": {
            "presets": ["stage-0", "react", "babili"]
        }
    },
    "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        "assets",
        "view",
        "public",
        "test",
        "spec",
        "logs",
        "lib/jasmine_examples",
        "db"
    ]
}
```

And I run `babel` from command line like this:

```
./node_modules/.bin/babel . -d ~/app_compressed/
```

And `babel` starts compressing `node_modules` directory:

```
node_modules\apache-crypt\gensrc\index.js -> C:\Users\user\app_compressed\node_modules\apache-crypt\gensrc\index.js
node_modules\apache-md5\gensrc\index.js -> C:\Users\user\app_compressed\node_modules\apache-md5\gensrc\index.js
node_modules\babel-preset-env\data\built-in-features.js -> C:\Users\user\app_compressed\node_modules\babel-preset-env\data\built-in-features.js
node_modules\babel-preset-env\data\plugin-features.js -> C:\Users\user\app_compressed\node_modules\babel-preset-env\data\plugin-features.js
node_modules\babel-preset-env\lib\default-includes.js -> C:\Users\user\app_compressed\node_modules\babel-preset-env\lib\default-includes.js
node_modules\babel-preset-env\lib\index.js -> C:\Users\user\app_compressed\node_modules\babel-preset-env\lib\index.js
```

Literally wrong behavior. How to fix it? How to make `babel` ignore folders specified in config?

Comment: I have had so many issues with ignore. Generally my code is in an `src` folder and I just point Babel to it.

Answer (score 7):

ignore get array of regexes so try like this

```
ignore: [
 /node_modules/,
 ...,
]
```

or you can pass a callback function like this

```
ignore: [
   /node_modules/,
   function(filepath) {
      return filepath !== "/path/to/es6-file.js";
   },
]
```

Answer (score 5):

Babel dev team say that there is a bug and `ignored` in config file doesn't work now.

However, I found that if you pass ignored directories in command line (with `--ignored` option), all works well, as expected. You can even pass globs in command line, like `**/drafts`

```
./node_modules/.bin/babel . -d ~/app_compressed/ --ignore node_modules,test,assets,stuff,views,public,test,spec,logs,lib/jasmine_examples,db,routes/api/drafts,**/drafts
```

Comment: May you please link to this bug, I think I might be getting hit with it.

Comment: @Noitidart PR to fix: https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/3644  Supposedly fixed in 6.14 but seems to have regressed again in 6.24 and 6.26

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after moving a `Vue` project from `Cloud9` env to my PC and installing `npm` dependencies.

Solved this by:

1. updating the `Node.js` with [nvm for windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)
2. installing the `Vue CLI` globally and then running `build` in the `Vue UI`.

I am not sure what helped though.